# Issues with gradient of standard deviation in GPR using skopt.learning.gaussian_process

Tags: optimization, scikit-learn, gaussian-process, gradient, inverse-problem

I'm currently working on a Gaussian Process Regression (GPR) model using the implementation provided in skopt.learning.GaussianProcessRegressor which is a wrapper for the sklearn implementation. This wrapper provides gradients for the mean and std of predictive distribution through the [predict function](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/_modules/skopt/learning/gaussian_process/gpr.html#:%7E:text=%5Bdocs%5D%20%20%20%20def%20predict(self%2C%20X%2C%20return_std%3DFalse%2C%20return_cov%3DFalse%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return_mean_grad%3DFalse%2C%20return_std_grad%3DFalse)%3A).

I'm using these gradients in an inverse design process as surrogate models to find optimal X for a desired Y through optimisations. I've tested these gradients with a model (without a StandardScaler) on my data using [scipy.optimize.check_grad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.check_grad.html) with samples from my data as:

```
error = check_grad(lambda x: model.predict(x.reshape(1, -1), return_mean_grad=True)[0],
                   lambda x: model.predict(x.reshape(1, -1), return_mean_grad=True)[1],
                   x0_flat)
print("Mean gradient error:", error)

error_variance = check_grad(lambda x: model.predict(x.reshape(1, -1), return_mean_grad=True,return_std=True, return_std_grad=True)[1],
                            lambda x: (model.predict(x.reshape(1, -1), return_mean_grad=True,return_std=True, return_std_grad=True)[3]),
                            x0_flat)
print("Std gradient error:", error_variance)
```

The errors in the gradient of mean are quite low (around 1e-05 to 1e-06) but the errors in gradient of std are always quite high (0.5 to 2.5). Is this expected for the gradients of standard deviation to be very different from approximated gradients from finite differences? Or could I be doing something wrong?